# Mapping, sum, and conditions in python

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to make this more efficient?

I am using the congressional dataset in the “Data Folder”
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/congressional+voting+records

to answer How many republic4ns voted “n0” for at least 10 of the topics? D3mocrats?

```
voters = Labels[Labels['class name'] == 'democrat']
non_no_locations = voters != 'n'
voters[non_no_locations] = 0
no_locations = voters == 'n'
voters[no_locations] = 1
Total_no = voters.sum(axis=1)
greater10 = Total_no >= 10
print(greater10.sum())
```

***edited to remove prints, it didn’t work without them before. Tried it again and it works.

I get lots of red in the console with this message

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Comment: Prints are probably the worst performing part of the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

topics_col = ["topic_%i" % i for i in range(16)]

df = pd.read_csv('house-votes-84.data', names = ['class name'] + topics_col)

df = df.replace('y', np.NaN).replace('?', np.NaN)
df['n_sum'] = df[topics_col].count(axis=1)

df[df.n_sum >= 10].groupby('class name')[['n_sum']].count()

## RESULT
#
#             n_sum
# class name       
# democrat       14
# republican     12
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, your approach definitely looks cleaner.

However, I received this error:

```TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple```

Comment: Strange! I didn't get anything like that. Did you execute the whole snippet ?

Comment: If so, can you add the whole trace ?